# cannot restore view pager fragment state

Tags: android

i have a view pager with 3 fragments. i use retrofit rest api to populate each of my fragments for the first time. What i would like to achieve is when the user swipes back either in first or third fragment(those 2 fragment are being being destroyed by the view pager) to restore the data(saved in an array list) and not make a rest api call again. What i have done is to save the array list of downloaded data in onSaveInstanceState() and successfully retrieve it when the user swipes back to one of the 2 above fragments only FOR THE 1 FIRST TIME. The problem is when i navigate back to either one of the 2 fragments the specific bundle key where the array list was saved contains null value.

CompletedSurveysFragment(the third fragment):

```
public class CompletedSurveysFragment extends Fragment implements SAMVCView {

    private static final String debugTag = CompletedSurveysFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private View view;
    private RecyclerView completedSurveysRcV;
    private SAMVCPresenterImpl SAMVCpresenterImpl;
    private SurveysRcvAdapter surveysRcvAdapter;
    private List<SurveyData> data;

    public CompletedSurveysFragment() {}

    public static CompletedSurveysFragment newInstance() {
        return new CompletedSurveysFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(debugTag, "onCreateView");
        if ( view == null ) view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_completedsurveys, container, false);
        completedSurveysRcV = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.completedSurveysRcV);
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: 21/6/2016 configure Limit and offset values
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(debugTag, "onActivityCreated " + savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        completedSurveysRcV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        completedSurveysRcV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        completedSurveysRcV.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider)));
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            SAMVCpresenterImpl = new SAMVCPresenterImpl(this);
            SAMVCpresenterImpl.getSurveysBasedOnSpecificFirmId(new AllSurveysBody(getResources().getString(R.string.list_surveys), LoginActivity.getSessionPrefs(getActivity()).getInt(getResources().getString(R.string.firm_id), 0), getResources().getString(R.string.completed), 8, 0));

            surveysRcvAdapter = new SurveysRcvAdapter(null, completedSurveysRcV);
            completedSurveysRcV.setAdapter(surveysRcvAdapter);
        } else {
            //Log.e(debugTag, savedInstanceState.+"");
            if (savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("data") != null) {
                Log.e(debugTag, "here "+ savedInstanceState);
                surveysRcvAdapter = new SurveysRcvAdapter(savedInstanceState.<SurveyData>getParcelableArrayList("data"), completedSurveysRcV);
                completedSurveysRcV.setAdapter(surveysRcvAdapter);
                surveysRcvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            //Log.e(debugTag, getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data")+"");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) this.data);
        Log.e(debugTag, "CompletedFragment onSaveInstanceState "+ outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccessSurveysFetched(List<SurveyData> data) {
        this.data = data;
        surveysRcvAdapter = new SurveysRcvAdapter(data, completedSurveysRcV);
        completedSurveysRcV.setAdapter(surveysRcvAdapter);
        surveysRcvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {

    }
}
```

View pager adapter:

```
public class SurveysPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private static final String debugTag = SurveysPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<SurveyData> data;
    String[] tabText;

    public SurveysPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String[] tabText) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.tabText = tabText;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.e("SurveysPagerAdapter", position+"");
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return CompletedSurveysFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return OngoingSurveysFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return PendingSurveysFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabText[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're always returning a new instance of your fragment. Instead of calling `CompletedSurveysFragment.newInstance();` (and your other Fragments) every time user swipes, create an array of fragments and retrieve it this way:

```
    ...
    Fragment [] pages = new Fragment[getCount()];
    ...
     @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.e("SurveysPagerAdapter", position+"");
    switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    if(pages[position] == null)
                        pages[position] =  CompletedSurveysFragment.newInstance();
                    return pages[position];
    ...
    }
```

Then, you can fetch and cache your data in `onCreate()` and retrieve it later in `onResume()` in your respective fragments.

Comment: i am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if (pages.get(position) == null) pages.set(position, CompletedSurveysFragment.newInstance());
                return pages.get(position);
            case 1:
                if (pages.get(position) == null) pages.set(position, OngoingSurveysFragment.newInstance());
                return pages.get(position);
            case 2:
                if (pages.get(position) == null) pages.set(position, PendingSurveysFragment.newInstance());
                return pages.get(position);
            default:
                return null;

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because onSaveInstanceState only occurs when the parent activity is closed.  Since the parent activity of your viewpager is still active when you switch between your fragments, onSaveInstanceState will not be called.

To get the data to save like you are intending, what I would likely do instead is save the data in `onPause()` and retrieve the data in `onResume()`.

**EDIT**

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) you need to put the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` after you modify the `Bundle`.

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is always called when the fragment is destroyed...checked using log..

Comment: I have edited my answer.  It looks like if the onSaveInstanceState is being called, the super needs to go last so that the modified savedInstanceState object is passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `onPause()` and `onResume()` won't work. Fragments are tied to their parent activity so since you browse through fragments parent activity is on an `onResume()` status. What I suggest you to do is to use singleton objects to fetch and store your data. Each fragment can keep a reference to the respective object and have instant access to the data you need. There is plenty of info about singleton pattern and how it works.